# localhost not working in docker for mac

Tags: php, macos, apache, docker, docker-compose

I am using latest Docker for mac. I am running into this strange issue. I can access my webapp via http://127.0.0.1/ but not http://localhost/ however I can access https://localhost/ (self signed cert). So, I am not sure what is wrong here.

This is my docker compose.

```
version: "3"
services:
  php:
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html
      - conf:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
```

and this is my Apache config

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
  ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
  DocumentRoot /var/www/html

  <Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
  <VirtualHost _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certs/localhost.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certs/localhost.key

    <FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </FilesMatch>

    <Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
    </Directory>

    BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-6]" \
        nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
        downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0
    BrowserMatch "MSIE [17-9]" ssl-unclean-shutdown

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

  </VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link but I am not using Xampp here. Also here in my case https://localhost (with https) works not the http://localhost (with http)

Comment: My guess is that you have something else running on port 80 on your Mac outside of the docker container.

I would try mapping port 80 to something else - like 8000 and then see if you still have the https versus http issue.

So, for instance:

    ports:
      - '8000:80'

So, in your web browser, you would access it through 

http://localhost:8000

This seems especially likely since you CAN access https which is mapped to port 443.

Comment: I am afraid that is not the case here. I reverified it twice.

Comment: Have you checked your `/etc/hosts` file to see if localhost is mapped to 127.0.0.1?

`vi /etc/hosts`

If your loopback adapter is working to get you to that port, then perhaps your host entry is missing.  You should see this:

`127.0.0.1       localhost`

You could ping localhost to verify this as well ...  good luck!

Comment: It is mapped to localhost. Also I ran lsof command that you posted I got no result. I will try port remapping like you suggested.

Comment: I am reposting the port remapping for others:

How did you verify there's no service listening on port 80?  

You can verify with this command: `sudo lsof -i -n -P | grep ':80 (LISTEN)'`.

If you have run `docker-compose up`, you should see a line like this from Docker:

     `vpnkit     pid       user   22u  IPv4 0xhex      0t0    TCP *:80 (LISTEN)`.

If you see this, your Docker container is listening for TCP connections on port 80 through vpnkit process.  

If you see other lines besides the one I have above, you have other services that are listening on port 80.

Answer (score 13):

You can try with `docker.for.mac.localhost`

Comment: Now `host.docker.internal`. [Docs](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host)

Answer (score 11):

Just putting @danwild [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45538299/localhost-not-working-in-docker-for-mac#comment103227451_47619842) in answer form for more visibility.

You can now access localhost from within the container using `host.docker.internal`. See the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/networking/#use-cases-and-workarounds)